# jQuery tabs causing page to disappear

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zen-cart

Hope I can be as specific as possible.

I'm editing a ZenCart for my Dad's site and I'm using jQueryUI to display tabs in a dropdown box:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1860151/Untitled.jpg

To proof of concept it before I invest hours in it, I simply copied the example from jQueryUI.com as seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/egp346a5/

```
//tabs JS from jqueryui.com
$(function () {
    $("#tab").tabs({
        event: "mouseover"
    });
});


// html of tabs
<div id="tab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Inkjet</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">B&W Laser</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Color Laser</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1">
        <table id="inkjetTable">
            <tr>
                <td>Advent</td>
                <td>Dell</td>
                <td>Kodak</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brother</td>
                <td>Epson</td>
                <td>Lexmark</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Canon</td>
                <td>HP</td>
                <td>Samsung</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
        <table id="inkjetTable">
            <tr>
                <td>Brother</td>
                <td>Epson</td>
                <td>Lexmark</td>
                <td>Samsumg</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Canon</td>
                <td>HP</td>
                <td>OKI</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dell</td>
                <td>Kyocera</td>
                <td>Panasonic</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
        <table id="inkjetTable">
            <tr>
                <td>Brother</td>
                <td>Epson</td>
                <td>Lexmark</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Canon</td>
                <td>HP</td>
                <td>OKI</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dell</td>
                <td>Kyocera</td>
                <td>Samsung</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works as seen when on the base page but when I goto any other page the entire page disappears just after load. When I comment out the tabs javascript the issue goes away so I think its safe to assume that its something to do with it. When I inspect the page in Chrome Dev there is a js event right at the end of the page load which I think is responsible but I'm not sure what is causing that.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean - "but when I goto any other page the entire page disappears just after load."

Comment: Are there any errors showing up in the browser console? (right click and 'inspect', usually). Also, is jQuery included on the other pages?

Comment: i'm editting it on my mac and using mamp for local server config. when i browse to localhost/, the page correctly loads and the menu works as shown above. on EVERY other page, the page loads but then when its 'finished', i.e. the last element loaded, js events occur which don't happen on localhost/ and the page disappears. i could screen shot these if that'd help.

no there are no errors is the console

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#tab").tabs({
        event: "mouseover"
    });
});
```

Comment: I was having the same issue long time ago maybe this will work. $(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
  // Actions to do
});

Comment: again no luck. thanks though. its so odd. when i look at the source of the page, when the code is run all the content of the page is deleted from the page. all that is left is head and body tags with one <a> tag there? i may just rethink my approach to this menu!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a base-tag on your page? Read here:

http://tjvantoll.com/2013/02/17/using-jquery-ui-tabs-with-the-base-tag/

I had a similar problem with page disappearing just after load. This solved it (almost). The cleanest solution didn't work with a url containing af query string. Had to omit the base tag.